# Is there another time that would/will work better for you?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Are these sentence grammatically correct?

1. Is there a time that would work better for you?
2. Let me know if there is a time that would work better for you.

Should these sentence use will instead?

Answer (score 1):

*Would* is softer, you're offering up the possibility of a more convenient time, if the person would like that. You're suggesting the *idea*, really! It sounds more polite to many people.

*Will* is more direct, similar to *is there a time that works better for you* - in a way, you're asking "do we need to change this time?" and that might make some people feel uncomfortable, like they don't want to cause trouble.

So either of them works, it's just that *would* can be more polite.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have always struggled with using modal verbs with the correct tenses in conditional sentences. When we are using would/could in a conditional or polite manner, we pair these modal verbs with "was/were" which confuses me as the sentences are referring to something that has not yet happened. But sometimes it's also correct to use present tense verbs with these modal verbs.

Comment: If you're just being polite, you use *would + infinitive* to add a little "distance" - *I would like*, *would this be better?* etc. When it comes to conditionals, we use the past tense to give things more of an "unreal" flavour, to imply something is unlikely (or didn't happen, but we're imagining it *did*). *If I **win** the lottery* and *if I **won** the lottery* both mean the same thing really, but *if I win* sounds much more like it could happen, that the person is going to buy a ticket, whereas *if I won* sounds more like a daydream. There's a lot to learn but it's all just speaking style

Answer (score 0):

I would say: What time do you think is convenient for you?